# Excel VBA Ribbon - Set value of editBox on Startup Based on Value on Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, editbox

I have an editBox on an Excel File where I want to display a date that is stored in a named cell on a specific worksheet. I want this value to be displayed when the Excel file is opened.

Here's the ribbon XML line:

`<editBox id="editBoxSDate" label = "S Date" onChange = "onChange_SDate" getText = "getText_SDate"/>`

Here's the getText_SDate function:

```
Public Function getText_SDate(ByRef control As Office.IRibbonControl) As String
    getText_SDate = CStr(wksSettings.Range("SettingsSDate"))
End Function
```

When I open the file and click on my custom Ribbon tab, I get the following error message:
[Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp9Aa.png)

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Either change the name of the `Function` or the `getText` command to match, actually they do not match, i.e.: `getText_Date` vs.`getText_SDate`

Comment: Sorry... I had to change some of the words in the code to make it non-descript. I corrected the original post. Same error though.